# Rendering Active Branch of Zend Navigation Without Top Level

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

I am rendering the top-level elements of a Zend Navigation object in one place like this:

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setMaxDepth(0);
```

How do I render the navigation tree from the second level on down for the active branch?  I've tried creating a partial that loops the `$this->container` object, but I don't know how to determine if my current item is the active branch.  Once I've determined that it's the active branch how do I render the menu?  Am I doing this the hard way and missing something obvious?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

I accepted a solution because that's what I used, but I also would like to provide the answer to my actual question, for reference sake. (`$this` is the view object)

```
// Find the active branch, at a depth of one
$branch = $this->navigation()->findActive($this->nav, 1, 1);
if (0 == count($branch)) {
    // no active branch, find the default branch
    $pages = $this->nav->findById('default-branch')->getPages();
} else {
    $pages = $branch['page']->getPages();
}
$this->subNav = new Zend_Navigation($pages);
```

`$this->subNav` can then be used to render the sub-menu.

Comment: where the index 'pages' in $branch['pages'] comes from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do something similar. My main navigation is handled with something like this...

```
$this->navigation()->menu()->setPartial('tabs.phtml');
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->render();
```

Then in my tabs.phtml I iterate over the container like so...

```
if (count($this->container)) {
  foreach($this->container as $page) {
    if ($page->isVisible()) {
      if ($page->isActive(true)) {
        $subcontainer = $page->getPages();
        foreach($subcontainer as $subpage) {
          // echo my link
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope that helps a bit.

Comment: The key I was missing is the `true` value for the `isActive()` function.  It makes the function recursive.

Comment: @Sonny, Always something simple, isn't it?!

Answer (score 5):

If I got your question right, this is how I do it:

```
print $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu(null, array(
    'minDepth' => 1,
    'maxDepth' => 1,
    'onlyActiveBranch' => true,
    'renderParents' => false));
```

Renders only the submenu of currently active menu.

Comment: That does indeed render the submenu of the active menu, but I wanted to always render from the second level down.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

```
<?php

// Render top-level elements
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setMaxDepth(0);

// Render 2nd level elements for active element
echo $this->navigation()->menu()
        ->setOnlyActiveBranch(true)
        ->setRenderParents(false)
        ->setMinDepth(1);

?>
```

but this is not a good solution. Better one for each level as a separate menu:

```
<!-- level 1 -->
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setMaxDepth(0); ?>


<!-- level 2 -->
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setOnlyActiveBranch(true)->setRenderParents(true)->setMinDepth(1)->setMaxDepth(1); ?>



<!-- level 3 -->
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setOnlyActiveBranch(true)->setRenderParents(false)->setMinDepth(2)->setMaxDepth(2); ?>
```

Comment: What happens if you're on a page that is in the third level?

Comment: Check this, I needed a 3-level menu, but with each level separate. So what i did is:

`
<!-- level 1 -->
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setMaxDepth(0); ?>

<!-- level 2 -->
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setOnlyActiveBranch(true)->setRenderParents(true)->setMinDepth(1)->setMaxDepth(1); ?>

<!-- level 3 -->
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setOnlyActiveBranch(true)->setRenderParents(false)->setMinDepth(2)->setMaxDepth(2); ?>

` 

I'm currently testing this, it seems to work fine, even on level 3 active.