# Zend View Helper Navigation removes active branch so breadcrumbs don't show up

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view, zend-navigation

Hey I want a layout in my header where I have the global menu, then the page menu and then breadcrumbs. To do this I, mostly, took away from this answer: [Rendering Active Branch of Zend Navigation Without Top Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496763/rendering-active-branch-of-zend-navigation-without-top-level)

This works great, except the active branch gets removed form the Zend_Navigation_Container that is registered.

This is how I do it:

```
<nav>
<?php 
//Create top level menu
echo $this->navigation()->menu()
        ->setUlClass('main')
        ->setMaxDepth(0)
        ->setIndent(4) 
        . PHP_EOL;

//Set to get the whole active branch
$this->navigation()
        ->setMinDepth(0)
        ->setMaxDepth(0);

//Retrive the active branch
$activeBranchTopLvl = 
    $this->navigation()->findActive(
        $this->navigation()->getContainer());

//Get the 2nd level pages for the active page
$activeBranch = $activeBranchTopLvl['page']->getPages();

$subMenu = new Zend_Navigation();

//This is the line that removes the active branch
$subMenu->setPages($activeBranch);

//Render 2nd level menu
echo $this->navigation()->menu($subMenu)
        ->setUlClass('sub')
        . PHP_EOL;

//Set up for breadcrumbs
$this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setMinDepth(0);
$this->navigation()->setMaxDepth(null);
$this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setRenderInvisible(true);

?>
</nav>
<p id="breadcrumbs"><?php echo $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->render(); ?></p>
```

The result is that the breadcrumbs are non-existant:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="main">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="/auth">Auth</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="sub">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="/auth/login">Log In</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/auth/logout">Log Out</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<p id="breadcrumbs"></p>
```

The active branch have been cut off to the top level, here is the Zend_Navigation_Container before its cut:

```
...
$subMenu = new Zend_Navigation();

print_r($this->navigation()->getContainer()->toArray());

//This is the line that removes the active branch
$subMenu->setPages($activeBranch);

//Render 2nd level menu
...
```

This Outputs the whole Container:

```
...
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Auth
            [fragment] => 
            [id] => 
            [class] => 
            [title] => 
            [target] => 
            [accesskey] => 
            [rel] => Array
                (
                )

            [rev] => Array
                (
                )

            [order] => 
            [resource] => 
            [privilege] => 
            [active] => 
            [visible] => 1
            [type] => Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc
            [pages] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Log In
                            [fragment] => 
                            [id] => 
                            [class] => 
                            [title] => 
                            [target] => 
                            [accesskey] => 
                            [rel] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [rev] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [order] => 
                            [resource] => 
                            [privilege] => 
                            [active] => 1
                            [visible] => 1
                            [type] => Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc
                            [pages] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [action] => login
                            [controller] => auth
                            [module] => 
                            [params] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [route] => 
                            [reset_params] => 1
                            [encodeUrl] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Log Out
                            [fragment] => 
                            [id] => 
                            [class] => 
                            [title] => 
                            [target] => 
                            [accesskey] => 
                            [rel] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [rev] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [order] => 
                            [resource] => 
                            [privilege] => 
                            [active] => 
                            [visible] => 1
                            [type] => Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc
                            [pages] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [action] => logout
                            [controller] => auth
                            [module] => 
                            [params] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [route] => 
                            [reset_params] => 1
                            [encodeUrl] => 1
                        )

                )

            [action] => 
            [controller] => auth
            [module] => 
            [params] => Array
                (
                )

            [route] => 
            [reset_params] => 1
            [encodeUrl] => 1
        )

)
...
```

This is after I add the pages to the new container:

```
...
$subMenu = new Zend_Navigation();

//This is the line that removes the active branch
$subMenu->setPages($activeBranch);

print_r($this->navigation()->getContainer()->toArray());

//Render 2nd level menu
...
```

The Output:

```
...
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Auth
            [fragment] => 
            [id] => 
            [class] => 
            [title] => 
            [target] => 
            [accesskey] => 
            [rel] => Array
                (
                )

            [rev] => Array
                (
                )

            [order] => 
            [resource] => 
            [privilege] => 
            [active] => 
            [visible] => 1
            [type] => Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc
            [pages] => Array
                (
                )

            [action] => 
            [controller] => auth
            [module] => 
            [params] => Array
                (
                )

            [route] => 
            [reset_params] => 1
            [encodeUrl] => 1
        )

)
...
```

I don't know why this happens as I create the new container and add the pages to it, it seems they are being removed from the container I have in Zend_Registry under the key Zend_Navigation.

Quickly, if I comment out that line the breadcrumbs works again and the container stays intact, but I lose the 2nd level menu of course:

```
...
$subMenu = new Zend_Navigation();

//This is the line that removes the active branch
//$subMenu->setPages($activeBranch);

//Render 2nd level menu
...
```

Output:

```
...
<nav>
    <ul class="main">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="/auth">Auth</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</nav>
<p id="breadcrumbs"><a href="/auth">Auth</a> &gt; Log In</p>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not pretty I used a custom function to get the array of Zend_Navigation_Page objects that was returned into an array of arrays which then kept the main navigation container intact so both menu levels and the breadcrumbs work.

header.phtml:

```
<nav id="global">
<?php 
//Create top level menu
echo $this->navigation()->menu()
        ->setUlClass('main navigation')
        ->setMaxDepth(0)
        ->setIndent(4)
        . PHP_EOL;

//Set to get the top level active branch
$this->navigation()
        ->setMinDepth(0)
        ->setMaxDepth(0)
        ->setRenderInvisible(true)
        ;

//Retrive the active branch
$activeBranchTopLvl = 
    $this->navigation()->findActive(
        $this->navigation()->getContainer());

//Get the 2nd level pages for the active page
$activeBranch = $activeBranchTopLvl['page']->getPages();

//create a function to make the array of page objects
//into an array of arrays, accomplished by modifying it as a reference
$arrayify = create_function(
        '&$value, $key',
        '$value = $value->toArray();'    
    );

//go through the array with the custom function
array_walk($activeBranch, $arrayify);

$subMenu = new Zend_Navigation();

//This is the line that removes the active branch
$subMenu->setPages($activeBranch);

//Render 2nd level menu
echo $this->navigation()->menu($subMenu)
        ->setUlClass('sub navigation')
        ->setRenderInvisible(false)
        . PHP_EOL;

//Set up for breadcrumbs
$this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setMinDepth(0);
$this->navigation()->setMaxDepth(null);
$this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setRenderInvisible(true);

?>
</nav>
<p id="breadcrumbs"><?php echo $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->render(); ?></p>
```